# Does dbt jinja's if block accept SQL functions when checking value?

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to create a logic flow in my dbt codes basing on dates. The first attempt looks like this:

```
{% if '2024-01-17' == dateadd(day,-1,current_date()) %}

select current_date() as the_date

{% else %}

select dateadd(day,-1,current_date()) as the_date

{% endif %}
```

This failed to compile with the error saying `current_date` is not defined.

I tried to quote the function in the if block as below:

```
{% if '2024-01-17' == 'dateadd(day,-1,current_date())' %}

select current_date() as the_date

{% else %}

select dateadd(day,-1,current_date()) as the_date

{% endif %}
```

It compiled fine but it's because dbt treats 'dateadd(day,-1,current_date())' as a string, and it doesn't equal to '2024-01-17' so it executes the {% else %} block.

This question was posted on 2024-01-18 so `dateadd(day,-1,current_date())` should be equal to '2024-01-17', so ideally the {% if %} block should be executed.

What should I change so that the {% if %} block is executed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is to use dbt's Jinja variable `run_started_at` (see docs [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_started_at)):

```
{% if run_started_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2024-01-17' %}

  select current_date() as the_date

{% else %}

  select dateadd(day, -1, current_date()) as the_date

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have yesterday date as a string in Jinja2, you can try the following:

```
{% set yesterday = (modules.datetime.datetime.now() - modules.datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %}
```

Hence, your code transforms to:

```
{% if '2024-01-17' == (modules.datetime.datetime.now() - modules.datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %}

select current_date() as the_date

{% else %}

select dateadd(day,-1,current_date()) as the_date

{% endif %}
```

However, it is best practice to keep logic out of your templating. Moreover, SQL allows us to do exactly what you want:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE() - 1 = DATE('2024-01-17')
        THEN CURRENT_DATE()
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE())
    END AS the_date
```

If your date is a variable, you can also use it directly in your SQL code like this:

```
{% set date_check = '2024-01-17' %}
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE() - 1 = DATE('{{ date_check }}')
        THEN CURRENT_DATE()
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE())
    END AS the_date
```

I hope this helps!